# TextToSpeech not working on fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-text-to-speech

I am quite new to Android programming! I have managed to have TTS work but not for fragments. I am trying to swipe some images, and speak something each time I do that. I am not getting any error, however, the text is not spoken. Here's the code:

```
package com.example.nightrain.sliderTTS1;

import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.speech.tts.TextToSpeech;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import java.util.Locale;

public class Wild extends FragmentActivity{

    ImageFragmentPagerAdapter imageFragmentPagerAdapter;
    ViewPager viewPager;
    public static final String[] IMAGE_NAME = {
            "1", "2", "3"};
    static final int NUM_ITEMS = IMAGE_NAME.length;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);

        imageFragmentPagerAdapter = new ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
        viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        viewPager.setAdapter(imageFragmentPagerAdapter);
    }

    public static class ImageFragmentPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
        public ImageFragmentPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return NUM_ITEMS;
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            SwipeFragment fragment = new SwipeFragment();
            return fragment.newInstance(position);
        }
    }

    public static class SwipeFragment extends Fragment implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener {

        private static TextToSpeech tts;

        @Override
        public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                                 Bundle savedInstanceState) {

            View swipeView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.swipe_fragment, container, false);
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) swipeView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
            Bundle bundle = getArguments();
            int position = bundle.getInt("position");
            String imageFileName = IMAGE_NAME[position];
            int imgResId = getResources().getIdentifier(imageFileName, "drawable", "com.example.nightrain.sliderTTS1");
            imageView.setImageResource(imgResId);

            tts = new TextToSpeech( getActivity(), SwipeFragment.this );
            speak("help");

            return swipeView;
        }

        static SwipeFragment newInstance(int position) {
            SwipeFragment swipeFragment = new SwipeFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putInt("position", position);
            swipeFragment.setArguments(bundle);
            return swipeFragment;
        }

        public void onInit(int status) {
            Log.d("Speech", "OnInit - Status ["+status+"]");

            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                Log.d("Speech", "Success!");
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.US);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onDestroy() {
            if (tts != null) {
                tts.stop();
                tts.shutdown();
            }
            super.onDestroy();
        }


        public void speak( String text){
            tts.speak( text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null, "1" );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I was trying to use *speak()* before *onInit()*. It is interesting that I could use speak outside *onInit()* with no issues in activity, however, for fragment I needed to mode the *speak()* method and all necessary code inside *onInit()*. Since it is system called, I could found no way to force it to work outside it.

Comment: You can't use `speak()` until the voice engine has initialised. If it works somewhere else in you code, it's simply because it's winning the race condition. It won't happen every time.